# Tonal Language with more than 5 tones

Tags: list-of-languages, tonal-languages

I'm searching for languages which use a lot of different tones. The one with the most tones I found was Thai which has 5 tones. Are their tonal languages with use more distinct tones than thai?

Comment: you'll find such languages without much effort in mexico, central africa, and southeast asia. have a look at [this paper](http://linguistics.berkeley.edu/phonlab/annual_report/documents/2010/Hyman%20PLAR%20How%20To%20Study%20a%20Tone%20Language.pdf) for starters.

Comment: By "tones" you mean "tonal contours" or "tone levels"? E.g. most Chinese languages have just 5 tone levels, but use much more "tones" by having the tone go raising, falling, up-down-up, etc.etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how you analyze it, [Trique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trique_language) may have as many as 15 tones, built from 5 pitch levels.

Comment: Very tricky indeed then.

Comment: @hippietrail Ha ha.

Answer (score 5):

Vietnamese has six tones.Cantonese has nine.

Comment: Do you think you could expand this answer by adding information on what tones they have? Very short answers are discouraged by the SE guidelines ;)

Comment: That depends on how they're transcribed and what tonal theory is being used for the tonemics. Tones are not just pulled from a bag; they're very complex. Anyone who's looking for the tones can go to the source.

Comment: Which source? Are you asking us to do our own tonal analysis from scratch? Or are you saying there is only one possible analysis and therefore only one (the) source? ...

Comment: Indeed. There are always different ways to analyse the phonology of any given language. In Vietnamese we have at least a well-established standard orthography, which distinguishes six tones by means of special diacritics.

Comment: Well-established standard orthographies don't always capture everything. Written Lao distinguishes five tones yet in the north of Laos there is agreement that there are six tones. And in the capital there is no agreement on whether thare are five or six tones. Written Vietnamese has certain quirks in its attempts to fit both northern and southern Vietnamese varieties, which differ even more than northern and southern Lao varieties. I do not know whether all varieties of Vietnamese have the same number of tones. My point is that you can't rely on the writing sytem to tell you everything.

Comment: Vietnamese quốc ngữ script reflects Hanoi dialect as it was spoken in the early 17th century and the spelling has not changed significantly since 1651 (Alexandre de Rhodes’ “Dictionarium Annamiticum”). It does not attempt to represent any other dialect. Quốc ngữ distinguishes 6 tones, as does modern Hanoiese, but most Southern dialects have only 5 tones.

Comment: @fdb: Thanks for the corrections and extra info!

Comment: Cantonese can be analyzed as having only six tones; three of the tones in the nine-tone analysis only appear on the so-called "checked" syllables, and they are in complementary distribution with their equivalents on open syllables.

Comment: I understand. In Vietnamese too you can distinguish the checked and non-checked versions of the sắc and nặng tones, in which case you will an eight-tone system.

Comment: I've never heard the term "checked tone" before and even Vietnamese text books never mention this. After reading the wikipedia article about this I do admit that syllables that end with -p, -t, and -k have only 2 tones: sắc and nặng. I didn't know the technical name for this before

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc. I was referring to pairs like má versus mát. There are probably better terms than “unchecked” versus “checked”; I am open to suggestions.

Comment: actually modern quốc ngữ is a dialect neutral script as it represents all phonemes and tones in every dialect. For example Northern dialects do not distinguish r/d/gi, tr/ch, s/x, Souther dialect speakers pronounce syllable ending sounds t/c/ch, n/ng, n/nh the same, some dialects also don't differentiate n and l. There are also many other dialect differences but they all are reflected in the script. If the script was only records Hanoi dialect then there's no need to write those consonants differently, only z, ch, s is enough

Comment: "According to Hannas (1997), there are 4,500 to 4,800 possible spoken syllables (depending on dialect), and the standard national orthography (Quốc Ngữ) can represent 6,200 syllables (Quốc Ngữ orthography represents more phonemic distinctions than are made by any one dialect)." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnamese_phonology#Syllables_and_phonotactics

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc. Please read what I actually said in my comment. I did not say that quốc ngữ represents the modern pronunciation in Hanoi; I said that it represents the dialect spoken in Hanoi in the 17th century (which some authors call "Old Vietnamese"). Modern Hanoi dialect has indeed lost some of the phoneme contrasts indicated by the script.

Comment: If that's true then it is very strange to here Northern dialects with those sounds. Do you have any source on this? I wonder why it lost so much phonemes

Comment: There is a detailed discussion of Old Vietnamese phonology in Thompson's "Vietnamese reference grammar".

Answer (score 4):

[**Lao**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lao_language) has five tones (like Thai) in the south.

But Lao has six tones in the north.

... In the capital, Vientiane, which is supposed to set the standard for the Lao language, [there has been an ongoing debate about whether the local spoken variety has five or six tones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lao_language#Indication_of_tones). I encountered teaching materials bluntly stating five, others bluntly stating six, and others mentioning the debate before arbitrarily choosing one analysis or the other before continuing.

Comment: That's interesting.  Doesn't written Lao distinguish 6 tones, given how the system with consonant classes works?  I thought Lao had 6 tones (high, mid, low, rising, high falling, low falling).  Do you happen to know which of these is missing in the 5 tone version?

Comment: I don't know off-hand. When I was in Laos I read many web pages and PDFs on the topic that I found via Google. But now I've just crossed from China to Mongolia. The Lao script has the same tone marks as Thai script but I'm definitely not an expert and could be wrong. We do have a Thai/Lao expert on the site though, if you ask a question about it I'm sure he'll answer.

Comment: In any case, I would bet these varieties of Lao are mutually intelligible, as speakers would be able to adjust for the slight discrepancy in the tones.  I'll be in Hanoi next week - another exotic linguistic destination :)

Answer (score 4):

Lanna ( northern thai ) has six tones as well

Answer (score 3):

Most dialects of Wú have 7 or 8 tones, however some such as those around Wujiang have up to 12 or 15 tones, depending on which topolect.

Ultimately, 5 tones is a pretty small inventory. Shanghainese has the lowest number of tones in Wú with 5.

Answer (score 0):

The **Hmong** language has 8 tones.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but just a note: you could specify that Dananshan has 8, while Hmong Daw and Mong Njua have 7.